# C# Datatable group, select and sum

Tags: c#, linq, select, sum

I have a datatable that looks like this

[image]

Once the datatable is populated, I use the code below to group by name and sum.

```
    var result = from tab in dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
                         group tab by tab["Name"]
                         into groupDt
                         select new
                         {
                             Agent = groupDt.Key,
                             Commision = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["Amount"].ToString()))

                         };
```

That gives me this outcome, the thing is I am missing the FixedSalary column. However it seems like I can only access the column data if I sum it like I do with `Commision = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["Amount"].ToString()))` - And I don't want to sum that column.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: How should be the result with the FixedSalary column? For example, could Nicklas Christensen have two different FixedSalaries or is it always the same?

Comment: No the fixed salary will always be the same on all rows - but can vary from each name

Comment: When you group you get a two dimension array [group][items].  So the sum enumerate through the items.  If you need other data you can use First(), Last(), Select(y => ....) or similar to enumerate the array.   In your case probably FixedSalary =  groupDt.First().FixedSalary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fixed salary is always the same for the Name, you can use this :

```
var result = from tab in dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
                     group tab by tab["Name"]
                     into groupDt
                     select new
                     {
                         Agent = groupDt.Key,
                         Commision = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["Amount"].ToString())),
                         FixedSalary = groupDt.Select(r => r["FixedSalary"].ToString()).FirstOrDeafult()
                     };
```

İf it can be change, you should group it with the name column.

Comment: Yes I've had thunnel vision on this for an hour now, thanks!